# get center coordinate image using matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, coordinate

eg I want to find the color values ​​of the center of this image

[image]

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean

```
img = imread('img.jpg');
color = img(round(end/2), round(end/2), :)
```

?